# Countdown timer shown inside of button in UIAlertController then enable button swift

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

Is it possible to create a UIAlertController that has a button that is initially disabled and has a 5 then 4 then 3..2..1 then enabled.

I want the user to actually read the message inside the controller and i figure that will be annoying enough to actually stop them from mindlessly tapping OK

If its possible how would I start going about doing this?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its little hacky as we are trying to modify the read only property of `UIAlertAction`. However it works fine for me. Alternatively you can create your custom view controller that looks like UIAlertController:

```
var timer: NSTimer?
var timerCount: Int = 5    
func showAlertView() {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message of alert", preferredStyle: .Alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)
            okAction.enabled = false

            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
            presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
                self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.countDownTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            }
        }

        func countDownTimer() {
            timerCount -= 1

            let alertController = presentedViewController as! UIAlertController
            let okAction = alertController.actions.first

            if timerCount == 0 {
                timer?.invalidate()
                timer = nil

                okAction?.setValue("Ok", forKey: "title")
                okAction?.enabled = true
            } else {
                okAction?.setValue("Ok \(timerCount)", forKey: "title")
            }
        }
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. is there any chances to get some trouble in future ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can enable alert action after specific interval by this way :

```
func showAlert() {
    let alertview = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "msg", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alertview.addAction(action)
    self.presentViewController(alertview, animated: true) { () -> Void in
        action.enabled = false
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "enableBtn:", userInfo: action, repeats: false)

    }
}

func enableBtn(t: NSTimer){
    let info = t.userInfo as! UIAlertAction
    info.enabled = true
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is *my* variation of the [Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37338363/14414215)

I found out that I had to invalidate the timer for every Option provided to the user in the `UIAlertController` otherwise the timer would continue to run in the background as well as cause some other issues.

My own implementation is a bit more involved and has more options but the gist is per below.
Also updated to Xcode 14

```
  var timer: Timer?
  var timerCount: Int = 5
  
  func showAlertView() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message of alert", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    okAction.isEnabled = false
    
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: {( action: UIAlertAction ) in
      print("No")
      self.invalidateAlertControllerCountDownTimer()
    }))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Maybe", style: .cancel, handler: {( action: UIAlertAction ) in
      print("Maybe")
      self.invalidateAlertControllerCountDownTimer()
    }))

    
    present(alertController, animated: true) {
      self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.alertControllerCountDownTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
  }
  
  @objc func alertControllerCountDownTimer() {
    timerCount -= 1
    
    let alertController = presentedViewController as! UIAlertController
    
    if let alertController = alertController {
      let okAction = alertController.actions.first
      
      if timerCount == 0 {
        invalidateAlertControllerCountDownTimer()
        okAction?.setValue("Ok", forKey: "title")
        okAction?.isEnabled = true
      } else {
        okAction?.setValue("Ok \(timerCount)", forKey: "title")
      }
    }
  }
  
  func invalidateAlertControllerCountDownTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
    timerCount = 5
  }
```